# matlab 2014b glnxa64/jre/bin/java: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Tags: software-installation, java, 14.10, matlab

I'm trying to install Matlab 2014b on Ubuntu 14.10, after giving

```
sudo ./install
```

it immediately exits with

```
/tmp/mathworks_7552/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin/java: 1:
/tmp/mathworks_7552/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin/java: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Can you help me, please??

[EDIT] The lines where I think it stops (install_unix script)

```
copyJREAndJarsToTmp () {
#
# Copy JRE and Jars to tmp
#
echo "Preparing installation files ..."      NEW_JRE_LOC="$TEMP_DIR/sys/java/jre/$ARCH/jre"
copyDirWritable "$JRE_LOC" "$NEW_JRE_LOC"
JRE_LOC=$NEW_JRE_LOC
JAVA_DIR="$TEMP_DIR/java"
JAR_LOC="$JAVA_DIR/jar"
JAREXT_LOC="$JAVA_DIR/jarext"
copyDirWritable "$ROOT/java" "$JAVA_DIR"
}
```

Comment: I would check the corresponding line in the install script and see what command it calls. Let us know what it is, then we can maybe figure it out.

Comment: tmp files get deleted as soon as the installation quits with the error above....I tried looking at the install_unix script...if it can be of any help, I think this is the last step executed

(added to the post)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `JRE_LOC` variable value and it works fine.

For this,
comment the line (inside the install file)

```
JRE_LOC=$NEW_JRE_LOC
```

and add path of the jre inside the matlab folder you have. For example:

```
JRE_LOC=/home/madhav/Desktop/study/Matlab_2011a_Linux/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/
```

and then run

```
sudo ./install -glnx86 -v
```

and it should work fine.